# Why do you need staged and online catalogs?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Product , catalogs etc both staged and online we have in Hybris...If we want show online the staged one we do synchronization but why we need staged products or catalogs?

Comment: just to add what hadnt been added as answer: You are not required to use staged/online catalogs. However, the default behavior in hybris is heavily geared about this paradigm and you will have to make more modifications if you want to get rid off that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifications of - Content, Product, Media,... - are made first in the staged catalog.

When changes/modifications are tested/approved and you are satisfied then you publish them to be available online to your users by synchronizing staged catalog to the online catalog.

Imagine if you have one single catalog, your users will be able to see unapproved and untested changes immediately, that's will increase the amount of risks and errors significantly.

Answer (score 3):

You allow the merch team to upload the proper visual, modify product texts etc... Then they can also test product pages with various device without any impact on the online website (online catalog).

It also allows to prepare seasonal catalog. For exemple you're in summer and you can start to work on the online version to be deployed on winter.

Answer (score 0):

Stage catalog is the one on which you work - change the data, etc. This catalog is not displayed in the storefornt.

[Online catalog](https://dcatalog.com/) is used in the storefront and should not be manually edited.

Usually there is synchronization between Stage and Online versions so that when the changes are approved for showing to the customers the synchronization is triggered and the products are available in the Online catalog (which implies storefront visibility).